# onSignalStrengthsChanged returns unknown signal strength 99 asu

Tags: android

I am currently writing an Android application for testing the signal strength. But then I have an issue regarding Signal strength readings. This codes are perfectly fine on other devices. But when I've tried it to Motorola(Froyo), It returns 99-asu UNKNOWN (Signal Strength). Any idea regarding this issue?. Thanks.

Currently I am using this code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).
    listen(signalStrengthListener,SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}

private class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener{  
@Override
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {
int strengthAmplitude = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();   
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strengthAmplitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);    
}}
```